# React Native - Cannot read property 'value' of undefined on form handling

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

so I'm having my first experience with react native, and I'm creating an app that gathers user input and renders a collection of strings with the form parameters, but when I try to fill the input fields I keep having the same error:

```
Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

on form handling, how should I work around this? thanks for the attention.
here's the code:

```
import {React, useState} from 'react';
import {
  TextInput,
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';

const Home = () => {
  const [lines, setlines] = useState([
    {
      text: 'This is a default string',
      fontSize: 32,
      color: '#000000',
    },
  ]);
  const [line, setline] = useState({
    text: '',
    fontSize: '',
    color: '',
  });

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    setlines({...lines, line});
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text style={styles.desc}>Insert your quote here:</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={line?.text}
          onChangeText={e => setline({...line, [line?.text]: e.target.value})}
        />
        <Text style={styles.desc}>Insert choose font size:</Text>
        <TextInput
          keyboardType="numeric"
          style={styles.input}
          value={line?.fontSize}
          maxLength={3}
          onChangeText={e =>
            setline({...line, [line?.fontSize]: parseInt(e.target.value, 10)})
          }
        />
        <Text style={styles.desc}>Insert choose Hex color:</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={`#${line?.color}`}
          maxLength={7}
          onChangeText={e => setline({...line, [line?.color]: e.target.value})}
        />
        <Button
          onPress={handleSubmit}
          title="Generate paragraph"
          color="#841584"
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
        {lines.map((myLine, index) => (
          <Text
            key={index}
            // eslint-disable-next-line react-native/no-inline-styles
            style={{
              fontSize: myLine.fontSize,
              color: myLine.color,
              margin: 15,
            }}>
            {myLine.text}
          </Text>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  desc: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 'auto',
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default Home;
```

Tried to handle the inputs inline, but didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've corrected your code in a few places. Here is [a snack](https://snack.expo.dev/1rlL9WEPG)

```js
import {React, useState} from 'react';
import {
  TextInput,
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';

const Home = () => {
  const [lines, setlines] = useState([
    {
      text: 'This is a default string',
      fontSize: 32,
      color: '#000000',
    },
  ]);
  const [line, setline] = useState({
    text: '',
    fontSize: '',
    color: '',
  });

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    setlines([...lines, line]);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text style={styles.desc}>Insert your quote here:</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={line.text}
          onChangeText={text => setline({...line, text })}
        />
        <Text style={styles.desc}>Insert choose font size:</Text>
        <TextInput
          keyboardType="numeric"
          style={styles.input}
          value={line.fontSize}
          maxLength={3}
          onChangeText={fontSizeStr =>
            setline({...line, fontSize: parseInt(fontSizeStr, 10)})
          }
        />
        <Text style={styles.desc}>Insert choose Hex color:</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={line.color}
          maxLength={7}
          onChangeText={color => setline({...line, color })}
        />
        <Button
          onPress={handleSubmit}
          title="Generate paragraph"
          color="#841584"
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
        {lines.map((myLine, index) => (
          <Text
            key={index}
            // eslint-disable-next-line react-native/no-inline-styles
            style={{
              fontSize: myLine.fontSize,
              color: '#' + myLine.color,
              margin: 15,
            }}>
            {myLine.text}
          </Text>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  desc: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 'auto',
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation [TextInput](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext) `onChangeText` calls the `callback functions` with the `text` which is entered inside the `TextInput`.

`e.target` is not a valid property,

I think you have some `ReactJs` background, due to which you are making this mistake.